# Sum of some elements in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, for-in-loop

I wonder how do I get the sum of some elements in an array?
for example, here's my array and I only need to sum up the first 5 elements:

```
var num = [31, 28, 31, 30, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 29, 31, 31]
```

I tried doing it with range, but it didn't work out:

```
for I in 0..<num[5] {
  .....
}
```

Comment: Having an array be called `num` (singular) is very confusing. A consider a better name like `let numbers = [31, 28, 31, 30, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 29, 31, 31]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for I in 0..<nums[5]` doesn't work the way you expect, because `nums[5]` is saying "the fifth (0 indexed) element of `nums`". So it's *as if* you wrote:

```swift
for i in 0..<31 { ... }
```

which is not what you want.

To iterate over the first 5 elements of your `num` array, you'll want to slice it first. Here's two ways to do that:

1. Ask for a 5-element prefix:

   ```swift
   for n in nums.prefix(5) { print(i) }
   ```
2. Slice it from the start, to its 5th element (at index 4):

   ```swift
   for n in nums[...4] { print(i) }
   ```

   This isn't as robust, because it'll crash if the array isn't long enough, unlike the `prefix` based approach (which just pulls as many as elements as available, up to 5 max.)

Both of those answers would print the first 5 numbers (31, 28, 31, 30, 30).

To sum them, you'd either do it manually with a loop:

```swift
var sum = 0

for n in nums.prefix(5) { sum += n }

print(sum)
```

Or more succinctly with `reduce`:

```swift
let sum = nums.prefix(5).reduce(0, +)
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried using a subarray?
Something like

```
for I in num[0...4] {
  //... your code here
}
```

Also for the sum you can use .reduce

```
let total = num[0...4].reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: This would crash if the array has less than 5 elements

Comment: Use prefix to prevent crash

Comment: Yeah, but that was not the point of the question. We don't know if it should return the sum of the 3 elements, if only 3 are available or throw an exception because the business rule demands it to be specifically 5 elements
Anyway it is easy to be solved in many ways, I like to put the max index inside a variable, containing the min between 5 4 and the array length, but this only makes sense if that is the desired rule (and we don't know that hehe)